# Can you provision a physical host with docker-machine?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

Can you provision a physical host with docker-machine or must it be on a VM.

Im currently using docker-machine on ubuntu 18.04 host to provision another ubuntu 18.04 host.

Input:

```
   $ docker-machine create \
     --driver generic \
     --generic-ip-address=192.168.1.3 \
     --generic-ssh-key ~/.ssh/id_rsa \
     server2
```

Output:

```
Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: Too many retries waiting for SSH 
to be available.  Last error: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker Machine is for VMs not physical hosts.